# Widget Not showing up after phone restart

Tags: android, android-widget

I created a widget that works great until I restart the phone, then the widget doesn't display it is invisible but if i hold and click i can throw it in the garbage

I have a function that is called from my configure activity in my widgetprovider that does the following:

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int appWidgetId, int version) 
 {
        if(savedType == -1)
            savedType = version;
//   android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

    Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, Configure.class);
    configIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);


    Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            Uri.parse(appWidgetId + "://widget/id/")
            ,String.valueOf(appWidgetId));
    configIntent.setData(data);




    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
    (context, 0, configIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.MainImage,pendingIntent);

    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.MainImage, lv_images[version]);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}
```

I had my onUpdate not doing anything because there is never anything to update but thinking this would be called after a phone restart i copied the code i had in the function

```
for(int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; ++i)
{
     updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i], savedType);
}
```

but this didn't seem to do much either.... suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When phone restart, it will call onEnable instead of onUpdate.

--update--

```
int[] allids = AppWidgetManager
    .getInstance(Context)
    .getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(Context, YourAppWidgetProvider.class);
```

This will get all ids that is under the *control* of YourAppWigetProvider. Read more on [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html)

Comment: ... onEnable only takes in a context.... so how would I do the update code in this?

Comment: Can you please share some basic code of onEnable method so that i come to know about it.